# Video pause on scroll (React.js | material UI)

Tags: reactjs, video, react-player

I have a video on my site that I want to be paused when I scroll it and play only when its visible. I have tried some solutions from internet but things are not working out.
This is my current code. I have tried out a solution from stackoverflow which shows me observe error. I would be glad if someone helps me out on this. Thank you.

Player.js

```
import { Box, Container } from "@mui/system";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import styled from "styled-components";
import videosample from "./homepagevideo.mp4";




const ResponsiveStyledPlayer = () => { 
        
    const Player = ({ className }) => (
        <ReactPlayer
          url={videosample}
          className={className}
          playing={true}
          autoplay={true}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          controls={false}
          muted
          loop={true}]
        />
      );
      
      const AbsolutelyPositionedPlayer = styled(Player)`
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      `;
      
      const RelativePositionWrapper = styled.div`
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 56.25%;
      `;
  
    return (
  <Box>
    <Container>
      <RelativePositionWrapper>
        <AbsolutelyPositionedPlayer />
      </RelativePositionWrapper>
    </Container>
  </Box>
)
};

export default ResponsiveStyledPlayer;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72656551/13081108 This answer might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you Waypoint for your requirement. I have made one demo for you, you can refer to that. Link [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4uevca?file=App.tsx)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube';
import { Waypoint } from 'react-waypoint';
import './style.css';

 export default function App() {
 let [shouldPlay, updatePlayState] = useState(false);

 let handleEnterViewport = function () {
  updatePlayState(true);
 };
 let handleExitViewport = function () {
  updatePlayState(false);
 };
return (
 <div>
   <Waypoint onEnter={handleEnterViewport} onLeave={handleExitViewport}>
     <div>
       <ReactPlayer
         playing={shouldPlay}
         url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U"
       />
     </div>
  </Waypoint>
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>hii</h1>
  <br />
</div>
 );
}
```